# How to get the percentage change from same time 7 days ago?

Tags: sql, postgresql, time

I have a big PostgreSQL database with time series data.

I query the data with a resample to one hour. What I want is to compare the the mean value from the last hour to the value 7 days ago at the same time and I don't know how to do it.

This is what I use to get the latest value.

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetime) AS time, AVG(value) as value, id FROM database 
GROUP BY id, time 
WHERE datetime > now()- '01:00:00'::interval
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE to calculate last week's average in the same time period, then join on id and hour.

```
    with last_week as
        (
        SELECT 
        id,  
        extract(hour from datetime) as time, 
        avg(value) as avg_value
        FROM my_table 
        where DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetime) = 
          (date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '7 DAYS'))
        group by 1,2
        )
    select n.id, 
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', n.datetime) AS time_now, 
    avg(n.value) as avg_now, 
    t.avg_value as avg_last_week
    from my_table n
    left join last_week t
      on t.id = n.id
      and t.time = extract(hour from n.datetime)
    where datetime > now()- '01:00:00'::interval
    group by 1,2,4
    order by 1
```

I'm making a few assumptions on how your data appear.

****EDIT - JUST NOTICED YOU ASKED FOR PERCENT CHANGE**

Showing change as decimal...

```
    select id, 
    extract(hour from time_now) as hour_now, 
    avg_now, 
    avg_last_week, 
    coalesce(((avg_now - avg_last_week) / avg_last_week), 0) AS CHANGE
    from (
        with last_week as
            (
            SELECT 
            id,  
            extract(hour from datetime) as time, 
            avg(value) as avg_value
            FROM my_table 
            where DATE_TRUNC('hour', datetime) = 
              (date_trunc('hour', now() - interval '7 DAYS'))
            group by 1,2
            )
        select n.id, 
        DATE_TRUNC('hour', n.datetime) AS time_now, 
        avg(n.value) as avg_now, 
        t.avg_value as avg_last_week
        from my_table n
        left join last_week t
          on t.id = n.id
          and t.time = extract(hour from n.datetime)
        where datetime > now()- '01:00:00'::interval
        group by 1,2,4
        )z
    group by 1,2,3,4
    order by 1,2
```

db-fiddle found here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rWJATypGzHPZ8sG2vXAGXC/4